# Tkinter python code is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here's my code:
It gives me an error that b is used before assignment.

```
from Tkinter import *
mConsole=Tk()
words=StringVar()
b='_ I _ _ U _'
def c():
    if b=='_ I _ _ U _':
        b='C I _ C U _'
            words.set(b)

words.set(b)
word=Label(textvariable=words, font='Jokerman 20').grid(row=1,column=3 ,columnspan=4)
```

Comment: It is, **in `c`** - presumably the full traceback refers to unbound locals? Please provide a [mcve] and the whole error.

Comment: Not totally related to your question, but: are you using a tutorial?

Comment: if that is your full code, that is probably not going to be your only error--you have to call `mConsole.mainloop()` as well, and you haven't called `c()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `globalize` the variable with the `global` command. After any function declaration, globalize any variables you intend on using.

In this case, you just have to add:

```
global b
```

at the top of your function and your code should work.

```
from Tkinter import *
mConsole=Tk()
words=StringVar()
b='_ I _ _ U _'
def c():
    global b
    if b=='_ I _ _ U _':
        b='C I _ C U _'
        words.set(b)

words.set(b)
word=Label(textvariable=words, font='Jokerman 20').grid(row=1,column=3 ,columnspan=4)
```

This resource may help: http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php

As a side note, I recommend more descriptive variable/function names.